# Using redis, how to identify active users based on their number of login during a period of time?

Tags: redis

I was told redis was born for analytic, and I came across some bitmap using cases. They are useful when counting based on yes/no(0/1), but I can't find an efficient way to count the number of user who login at least 4 times during the last 10 days. Because redis runs in memory, I tried using bit map to keep track login flag of each user, and using bitcount to filer, on my laptop, it took a minute to return the count from about 4Million users' login activity.

Is there any way to solve this problem? I guess the round trips between my node redis client and redis server may be the issue, I'll try batch command or lua script to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use SortedSets with user id in value, and timestamp in score.
When user logs in, score (time stamp) for this user updates to current. Than you can get ether N last logged in users (ZREVRANGE), or users, logged in between some datetime range (ZRANGEBYSCORE)